# Inserting sql Array using JDBC Template

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to insert sql Array using connection object with batchUpdate, my question is

Is there any chance that connection pool will get exhausted because i am using connection object from the prepared statement. I know i will get the same connection object in each iteration but  do I need to release the connection or not.

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TEST_ARRAY(ID, VAL_ARRAY) VALUES(?, ?)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
  @Override
  public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps, final int i) throws SQLException {

    Connection con = ps.getConnection();
    ps.setInt(1, rand.nextInt(10000000));
    ps.setArray(2, con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[]{"test1","test2"}));
  }

  @Override
  public int getBatchSize() {

    return 10000000;
  }
});
```

Comment: Which DataSource you are using? Can you share your xml or annotation code?

Comment: HI @ javaguy we are using dbcp2 with default configuration.